# Is there a way to do this with Java textareas?

Tags: java, parsing, styles, textarea, save

I have a question relating to java textarea. I know I could probably accomplish a textarea by using swing, but there is a feature in my textarea I need that I don't know if the one in swing can do for me. I need it so that there is `boolean H = false`, `when H = true` and someone is typing, the text they type is hightlighted (simply want a color overlayed, not selected), and I need a way to save this highlight and be able to parse the text area for this highlight. I plan on using some Java `Canvas` to get what I want done, not including the textarea. I know if I wanted I probably could just program the textarea in the `canvas`, but I feel like this would be really complicated, and if I should use `canvas` is there any way I can make it so I can still click and drag to select areas of text?

Comment: *"Java textarea issues?"*  Despite ending in '?', that is not a question.  What *is* your question?

Comment: *"relating to java textarea"*  DYM Java `JTextArea`?  If so, type that (or copy/paste the class name, if need be).  Programming is a precise matter, and it certainly helps to be exact when communicating with an audience where many people do not speak English as their native tongue.

Comment: By "highlight" do you mean the text should be selected?

Comment: You could use a `DocumentFilter` and a `JTextPane` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Why don't you just change the color of the text and update the UI?

Comment: @Masood_mj The issue is that I don't really want to change the text color, if I need to that's fine, but I'd prefer to highlight it, but my next issue is, how do I save the color whenever I save the text?

Comment: @Joni Simply color, not select.

Comment: @Richard Collins OK, so you need somehow to save the color code in the file. You can have your own file format. for example write c:color, t:text. You can also have XML to facilitate loading and saving using parsers (I'm sure later you want to add something more, so why not have a general format)